# CXF wadl2java generate code from grammar

Tags: rest, cxf, wadl

The code generation with for the methods works fine, but it seems to me that the grammar part is omitted because no Pojo and JAXB annotations are generated. Do I have to specify some additional configuration? I used this command: `wadl2java.bat -p packagename /path/to/wadl`
Here is a snippet of the wadl.

```
  <application 
  xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.tns.de">

  <grammer>
    <xsd:include href="file1.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <xsd:include href="file2.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <xsd:include href="file3.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <xsd:include href="file14.xsd"></xsd:include>
  </grammer>
  <resources base="http:localhost:8080/rest">
    <resource path="status/{id}" id="statusId">
      <param name="id" type="xsd:unsignedInt" required="true" default="" style="template"/>
      <method name="GET" id="getById">
        <request>
          <representation mediaType="application/json" element="tns:type1"/>
        </request>
        <response>
          <representation mediaType="application/json" element="tns:type2"/>
        </response>
      </method>
      ....
```

Comment: Are the xsd's also placed in same folder where the WSDL is?

Comment: Yes wadl and xsd's are in the same folder

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. There was a typo in the wadl. Previously I used `<grammer>` but you have to use `<grammars>`
Now it works.

```
<application 
  xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:tns="http://www.tns.de">

  <grammars>
    <include href="file1.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <include href="file2.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <include href="file3.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <include href="file14.xsd"></xsd:include>
  </grammars>
  <resources base="http:localhost:8080/rest">
    <resource path="status/{id}" id="statusId">
      <param name="id" type="xsd:unsignedInt" required="true" default="" style="template"/>
      <method name="GET" id="getById">
        <request>
          <representation mediaType="application/json" element="tns:type1"/>
        </request>
        <response>
          <representation mediaType="application/json" element="tns:type2"/>
        </response>
      </method>
```

Comment: I modified the answer